# Hybris SOLR get all products query

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrj, solrcloud, hybris-data-hub

I have the following requirement: when you make a search and there are NO results, display all the products within the active catalog version.
How can I make a query to fetch all the products from SOLR in Java? Is there any OOTB service that already fetch all products in a Catalog?

Comment: You can check `DefaultSolrProductSearchService` some methods to perform searches in Solr are available there

Comment: But how can I build a query to get all products with catalog version?

Comment: you can index only active catalog products in Solr, if this is okay with your set up. After all, only the active catalog gets displayed on the channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query as well to fetch the active catalog version products via Solr.

```
https://<your_domain>:<port>/solr/<solr_core>/select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=(catalogId:"<active_catalog_id>"+AND+catalogVersion:"<active_catalog_version>")
```

E.g.:

```
https://localhost:8983/solr/master_electronics_Product_flip/select?indent=on&q=*:*&fq=(catalogId:"electronicsProductCatalog"+AND+catalogVersion:"Online")
```